# What is the difference between Set Render Border and Set Render Border Camera Only?

Tags: render-border

In version 2.79b, and when in the 3D Editor area, two shortcuts call `view3d.render_border` with a parameter `camera_only`:

- <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> sets the parameter to `False`
- <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> sets the parameter to `True`

The later shortcut is actually assigned to two functions in the user preferences:

[image]

so, for the purpose of this question, I've disabled temporarily "Zoom to Border", to allow "Set Render Border" to be called. The configuration is:

[image]

My understanding:

- Those two `Set Render Border` shortcuts allow to define a rectangle in the one of the 3D view (not necessarily Camera view).
- The result is visible in the rendered image (F12) and/or in the 3D view but only when in shading mode "rendered"

In practical, when using any of them:

- In the 3D view, only the rectangle is shaded in "rendered" mode, the rest is shaded in "solid" mode.
- In the rendered output, only the rectangle is rendered, the rest is empty.

[image]

My question: What is the difference between the two shortcuts? Or is <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> (`camera_only = True`) an unintentional leftover?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SHIFT + B** lets you select a portion that you wish to see in the final render image or in the camera view.

[image]

**CTRL + B** lets you select  a portion you wish to see in the render view mode. to then delete the border is CTLR + ALT + B

[image]

while **CTLR + B** works also in camera mode, **SHIFT + B** if is not in the camera view mode acts as a zoom tool.

[image]

CTLR + B does not affect the camera view or the final render. unless you are already in camera view 
[image]

Comment: Please read after "*In practical, when using any of them*" where I explain I see the same result, so the question. No need to explain "zoom to border", I've disabled it to be able to compare both versions of "set render border".

Comment: I dont know how you compare them to see the same results, but again CTRL + B lets you have a preview box of your **render view mode**. thats not the same as the **final render**.  if you make a preview box with CTLR + B in the **render view mode** that wont affect your camera view nor your final render.

Comment: try it yourself. clear the border in your camera view so there won't be any confusion. then use the **CTRL + B** in your **3D view** (**not camera view as in camera view they do the same job**) to preview an area, then go in camera view or just do a render. you will see that you will have the full render resolution

Comment: Ah you're right! The difference is not visible when marking the border with (ctrl)(B) in the camera view, but as soon as the rectangle is created in another view, the rendered image is complete, but not with (shift)(B)

Comment: After some experimentation... Sh-B (camera only = true) is valid in camera view (no effect in other 3D views -- calls Zoom To Border if it shares the same shortcut). Its effect is to partially render the camera view, and to limit F12 render to the same area. Ctrl-B is similar to Sh-B: It partially renders the view in which it is defined, and limits F12 render (so it's identical if defined in camera view). It can be used independently in camera view and other views (two distinct areas can then be defined and cleared individually: one for the camera view, the other for all others views).